# Are there areas that have a higher chance of spawning dragons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It might be that I'm questing too much, but I don't see much dragons so I'm unable to learn the new words I learn. Are there areas I could go and take a visit to perform some efficient dragon hunting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather they appear generally every 36 or so hours. I tend to find them in towns when I'm waiting for shops to open.

I read somewhere that you can sleep for 36 hours in a town and when you go out a dragon spawns every time.

Also you need to do a quest in Whiterun as part of the story to allow attacks by "wild" dragons.

Comment: I've done the quest; the time between my two last dragons might have indeed been 36 hours but I'm not entirely sure. Someone needs to confirm whether force spawning by sleeping enough would work. I haven't seen a dragon attack Whiterun itself yet, is that possible?

Comment: @TomWijsman Yes, I've killed one right in Whiterun (and a single guard was the only NPC to die!)

Answer (score 2):

I've found that they're very likely to appear around the burial grounds, even after you've killed the first one guarding them.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Morthal, Winterhold, Falkreath, and Dawnstar spawn dragons nearly every time. Markarth had only one spawn and I have a house where I dump my gear after every quest or two. Karthwasten about every other time. Shor's Stone I don't visit very often so idk. Riften I've never had a spawn. Ivarstead about one in three. Been attacked between Ivarstead and Riften quite often.Windhelm I've never had attacked but I've been attacked at the farms near the stables. Rorikstead I've never had attacked but been attacked before and after. Solitude have had attacked twice, but get plenty of attacks a little ways away from the city. Same for Dragon Bridge. Whiterun never had a "wild" dragon attack, but a lot in the countryside and Riverwood. Think attacks have to do with how close dragon burials are, and where the dragons fly to. *Note this is just my current character at level 37.